# How do I install 12.04 after mounting the ISO in Windows?

Tags: installation, windows, iso

I would like to turn my Windows 8 desktop into a server. I downloaded the Ubuntu Server 12.04 server ISO and mounted it in Windows, but I don't get the option to install it?

How can I load up or configure some files to be able to launch the install program on Windows 8, so I can install Ubuntu Server 12.04 on a blank 500GB hard drive?

Please note that once Ubuntu Server is installed, I plan to format the hard drive with Windows on it so that Ubuntu is the only OS.

Comment: You *must* burn it.

Answer (score 4):

Since you intend to get rid of Windows 8, you will need to install Ubuntu 12.04 the old-fashioned way:

- Burning the ISO to a CD-R and booting your computer from the CD, or
- "Burning" the ISO to a USB and booting from the USB (use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sf.net) for that)

For your needs, you *cannot* install Ubuntu *from within* Windows like a regular Windows program. While you can run Ubuntu's Windows installer [(Wubi)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CGUQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.ubuntu.com%2FWubiGuide%2F&ei=B9okUKClMOiUiAL66oHACQ&usg=AFQjCNFCYNOR9uCsZJx-DIPcqoVozVEQcg&sig2=gduwOAF6pgrgKvxk0JApiQ&cad=rja) from Windows, that installation *requires Windows to function* -- you *cannot remove Windows*, or your Wubi will no longer work.

Comment: Yes you can(via Wubi), but you intended to **remove** Windows 8, so how can you install it in Windows, when you need to remove Windows?

Comment: @kyle Perhaps if you edited your question to explain *how you would do this with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 (or any other Ubuntu release, or any other GNU/Linux operating system)*, this would clarify what exactly you want to do. Right now, it sounds like you're saying you want to install Ubuntu *inside* your Windows 8 partition, then delete your Windows 8 partition, but still somehow have the Ubuntu system.

Comment: @kyle If you want to install Ubuntu while running Windows so it won't need Windows later, and you have a separate physical disk onto which you want Ubuntu installed, you may be able to create a virtual machine that uses that physical disk, and install Ubuntu on it, in such a way that it continues to work when its hardware changes from the VM's virtual hardware to the host machine's real hardware. But this is enormously complex compared to just booting from installation media and installing. So again, more information about what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful.

Comment: @EliahKagan: I think he simply wants to install a standard Ubuntu *but* from the ISO mounted in Windows, like you'd install say Office or a game, etc. without having to burn anything. Unfortunately, the only Ubuntu installer that will run in Windows is Wubi...